# Why does HttpContext.Current.User for Forms Authentication have Windows Username

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, forms-authentication, windows-authentication

I have a web application that uses custom (forms) authentication and authorization. After the user logs in i setup the GenericPrincipal using the username supplied. Authorization worked fine on Visual Studio 2012 IDE using IIS Express. However, I was getting authorization failures for users that seemed inexplicable on the web server I published to. I did a

```
Response.Write(HttpContext.Current.User.Name)
```

and published to the web server and I saw that my windows ID was returned instead of the custom user name I logged on with onto the site.

My configuration settings are not the problem, here is a sample of them

```
<system.web>
<authentication mode="Forms" >
      <forms loginUrl="Login.aspx" timeout="30" defaultUrl="Default.aspx" cookieless="AutoDetect" ></forms>
    </authentication>
    <authorization>
      <deny users="?" />
    </authorization>
</system.web>
```

Can anyone help me resolve this

Answer (score 0):

I found that this problem was caused by IIS configuration on the web server.

In my site's Authentication Settings in IIS, I had to **disable** all authentication modes(in my case *Windows Authentication*) **except** for *Anonymous* and *Forms* authentication.

I need Anonymous authentication to enable users to land on the Login page (otherwise IIS throws 401 Authorization Error)